# Simplify analytical expression that contains pseudoinverse and non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, pseudoinverse

I have a problem in a following form

$$\mathrm{C = A\underbrace{X(YX)^{+}Y}_{\neq I}B}$$

where $+$ indicates pseudoinverse.

$\mathrm{dim(C) = (L, 1) \\ dim(A) = (L, N) \\ dim(X)=(N, M) \\ dim(Y)=(M, N) \\ dim(B)=(N, 1)}$

and ${1<M<N<L}$

I have verified numerically that $$\mathrm{C=AB}$$ How do I prove it analytically?

Update:

$\mathrm{X = \matrix{x_{11} & z & z & \cdots & z & z \\ z & x_{22} & z & \cdots & z & z \\ z & z & x_{33} & \cdots & z  & z \\ \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots &  \\ z & z & z & \cdots & x_{M-1, M-1 } & z \\ z & z & z & \cdots & z & z \\ \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \\ z & z & z & \cdots & z & z}}$

with $\mathrm{ z > 0}$

Matrices are complex-valued and have full rank

Comment: Have you verified that numerically for all possible cases? On how many set of matrices have you checked that? Are some of the matrices full rank?

Comment: @KBS give me a sec, I will update a question

Comment: I have tried here and for some matrices I have that $AX(YX)^{+}YB\ne AB$, which is expected.

Comment: @KBS Matrix $X$ has a specific form. See updated question

Comment: Even with that, I have found matrices for which this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conditions you gave, I have the following counterexample:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 &0\\1 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\ B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\ X=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\ \mathrm{and}\  Y=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, we have
$$AX(YX)^{+}YB=\begin{bmatrix}0.75\\0.25\\0.25\\1\end{bmatrix}\  \mathrm{and}\ AB=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

So, I guess there is a need for extra assumptions.

It can be shown that the matrix $X(YX)^{+}Y$ is similar to the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}I & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

So let $M:=X(YX)^{+}Y$ and define $V$ to be a basis of the right-eigenspace of $M$ associated with the eigenvalue 1 (i.e. $MV=V$) and let $U$ be a basis of the left-eigenspace of $M$ associated with the eigenvalue 1 (i.e. $UM=U$). Define also $U_0$ to be a basis of the left null-space of $M$ and $V_0$ to be a basis of the right null-space of $M$. Those matrices can be chosen such that

$$\begin{bmatrix}U\\U_0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V & V_0\end{bmatrix}=I.$$

Now we can claim that $AMB=AB$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are such that $A=ZU+Z_0U_0$ and $B=VQ+V_0Q_0$ for some $(Q,Q_0,Z,Z_0)$ where $Z_0Q_0=0$

$$AMB=(ZU+Z_0U_0)M(VQ+V_0Q_0)=ZUVQ=ZQ$$ and $$AB=(ZU+Z_0U_0)(VQ+V_0Q_0)=ZQ+Z_0Q_0.$$

The result then follows.

Comment: I guess there is a small typo, namely $U$ is the basis of the **left**-eigenspace of $M$, or?

Comment: @Python That's correct. I am fixing this.

Comment: What if in my case, $MV=\mathbf{\lambda}^{T} V=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{1}\\\mathbf{0}
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\circ V\neq V$, where $\circ$ indicates that every column of $V$ is multiplied by the corresponding eigenvalue

Comment: I do not get what you mean. $V$ is by definition associated with the eigenvalues equal to 1. What are your vector $\lambda$ and $(1,0)$ above?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I did eigenvalue decomposition of $M$ in Python. I want to obtain the same values numerically as in your answer. In other words, I want to numerically prove that $MV=V$. I then hope to find $V$ in $B=VQ$ (which is unclear yet how to do). The same things I would do for $U$. Does what I do make sense and if not, is there another way to achieve my objective?

Comment: You can obtain $U,V,U_0,V_0$ by computing the normalized left- and right-eigenvectors.  You can compute $Q$, when it exists, V\B (in Matlab) or np.linalg.lstsq(V,B) in Python. Note that it will return a least-square solution when an exact solution does not exist. Another way is to compute $[V\ V_0]^{-1}B$ which is equal to $[Q\ Q_0]$.